# execute gsutil from airflow using python callable

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-storage

we want to run "gsutil ls -L gs://bucket/obj1" command to print the information of gcs object. we are using airflow to connect with gcs. can anyone help with syntax to run above command using python callable function

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [`GCSListObjectsOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/864cbc9cd843db94ca8bab2187b50de714fdb070/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/gcs.py#L163) provided by Google:

I think you can use it for your case with

```py
GCS_Files = GoogleCloudStorageListOperator(
                task_id='List_GCS_files',
                bucket='bucket',
                prefix='obj1',
                gcp_conn_id=google_cloud_conn_id
            )
```